# LPR Print Queue to File output Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, lpr

How can I set up a LPR Print Queue on a Windows 2008 Server and redirect the queued reports to a file location on the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [install](http://www.frogmorecs.com/arts/configure-lpdsvc) the LPDSVC in Windows to receive print jobs over lpr/lpd. Keep an eye on the event log for any error messages. You will probably need to enable [passthrough](http://www.frogmorecs.com/faq/printdistributor/lpd_passthrough) on the printer to avoid mangling the print file.

You will need some extra software to send the print to a file. We have a solution at http://www.frogmorecs.com/printdistributor.